# Is there any value in listing your high school on your CV?

Tags: resume

I'm an university graduate. On my CV, I just have my university listed. I attended high school in the US, but am currently residing in the UK. I'm wondering if I should include my high school, along with my grades when applying for my first job.

**What is customary and/or expected here?** Is there any value in listing my secondary education on my resume?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser UK, but I attended high school in the US.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @guest - The most obvious reasons are numerous grammatical errors.

Comment: @Donald: This (without comments) seems horrible for me (as I am not a native speaker, probably like the OP). For me, the only mistake is in the third word.

Comment: Edited for clarity/spelling

Comment: @guest - To be honest, the fact you think it is "horrible", is one of the reasons I didn't provide that comment.  I have been called way to many names by other users.

Comment: @Donald: I didn't want to call you horrible ans I am sorry if this came across. What I find horrible is the fact that this new user's question gets downvoted without any indication why for grammatic reasons (while the question is understandable) instead of that it gets edited and people rate on the usefulness of the question and comment on their votes as such.

Comment: @guest for what it's worth, the third word was actually probably right, and means something slightly different to the "graduate" that it has been edited to. A graduand has completed all the requirements to be awarded a degree, but has not actually been awarded it yet (i.e. they are waiting for the graduation ceremony). Once they recieve their degree they become a graduate.

Comment: @PlayerOne: Thank you! I did not know that. However, unfortunately for me, this was the closest to the "numerical grammatical errors" I could find.

Comment: @guest it seemed like a reasonable question to me too. People just like to downvote and close vote on this site.

Answer (score 4):

**Rarely, but it is sometimes useful.**

The only value to putting your high school would be if the person you are targeting also attended your high school and your high school is the kind of high school where that stuff matters to alumni. If you attended that kind of high school, you know.

Otherwise it doesn’t really matter. A university degree indicates that you graduated high school (or if you didn’t, that you could). Pretty much anything else is more helpful.

Comment: Since OP attended high school in a different country this *might* have some value as well.

Comment: @Lilienthal it could depend on if OP attended university in the US or UK.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a recent graduate, you should include your high school qualifications. It is up to you whether or not to name the school.

**Reasons to include high school qualifications**:

- In the UK we do not 'graduate' from high school. There is no single
  pass or fail qualification.
- UK bachelors' degrees tend to be more specialised than the USA. If
  you have any foreign languages or other useful subjects, these would
  be shown at high school level, not as minor subjects studied as part
  of your degree.
- UK school qualifications at 18 tend to be more advanced than the USA.
  They are regarded as useful - depending on where you are applying,
  and what for, having A Level or equivalent in sciences or languages
  could be viewed favourably by a recruiter, compared to someone else
  with the same degree but different A Level subjects. Therefore, UK
  recruiters expect to see these qualifications listed.
- Some school qualifications are considered mandatory for some jobs,
  which demand GCSE pass in English or Maths regardless of your degree
  subject. Therefore, you should include these (equivalent)
  qualifications.

You should usually omit fail grades.

**Reasons to omit the name of the school**

- If the name of the school indicates (or could be taken to indicate)
  an affiliation with a particular religious community

An example of a standard recent-graduate Curriculum Vitae is at

https://www.careers.ox.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Resource-Traditional-CV-Example.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I added high-school to my CV for a very practical reason. That was the only place where I studied programming in an organized way.

Adding that information brings some good weight to my CV - it shows that I studied programming languages in a specialized school under supervised professional guidance - instead of learning some coding by myself.

---

> Is there any value in listing your high school on your CV?

In my case, I would say that the value is huge - especially that I worked in software-related jobs.

The value of the information might have decreased slightly over time, since I proved times and again that I master the field in a professional way, not only academically.